# Flume Fetching Twitter Data

Tags: hadoop, flume-ng, biginsights, flume-twitter

While fetching the Twitter data through Flume, when I start the agent, I got the following error:

```
Unable to start EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource{name:Twitter,state:IDLE} } - Exception follows.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.FilterQuery.setIncludeEntities(Z)Ltwitter4j/FilterQuery;
at com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource.start(TwitterSource.java:139)
at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:44)
at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What could be my failure? I am a absolute beginner with Flume!

Comment: need more logs to see whats going on

Comment: While fetching data? It doesnt look like it started to fetch data... Can you add your flume conf file to the question?

Comment: i figured it out thanks :)